# How to pull groups from a column based on the unique combination of two other columns

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have data like this:

```
Sample_1    Apples  Red
Sample_2    Apples  Red
Sample_3    Apples  Red
Sample_4    Apples  Red
Sample_5    Apples  Red
Sample_6    Apples  Green
Sample_7    Apples  Green
Sample_8    Apples  Green
Sample_9    Apples  Green
Sample_10   Apples  Green
Sample_11   Apples  Yellow
Sample_12   Apples  Yellow
Sample_13   Apples  Yellow
Sample_14   Apples  Yellow
Sample_15   Apples  Yellow
```

How can I iteratively pull the samples from the first column based on the combination of the  groups formed from the other two columns, so that I get samples 1-5, 6-10 and 11-15?

What I ultimately want to do is pull the lists of samples (as the groups above) as input to another command, e.g.:

```
comm -23 <(sort <all_samples.txt>) <(sort <[input from above]>) > <difference.txt>
```

I have tried:

```
awk '{print $2"\t"$3}' <file.txt> | uniq
```

To get the unique combinations of the second and third columns, but I don't seem to be able to then do anything with this, especially pulling the first column, which is what I need.

Comment: So what format would this output be in? Do you just want the samples? The whole line?

Comment: Is input file ordered on columns 2 and 3? Ever? As in your example?

Comment: Yes, I just want the samples. (I have edited my code above to take out the file in the `comm` line (second `sort` command)). So ideally I don't want to save the samples as groups in separate files, I just want to be able to pull, e.g. the 'Red Apple' samples, and pass them as the input to another command. Thanks

Comment: @andcoz Yes, it is ordered.

Comment: I am sorry but I still cannot understand which output do you want. Please, add an example of the desired output.

Comment: So on the first iteration I want to be able to do: `comm -23 <(sort <all_samples.txt>) <(sort Sample_1 Sample_2 Sample_3 Sample_4 Sample_5) > <difference.txt>` (I have chosen this line of code more-or-less arbitrarily just to illustrate that I want the samples to be the input to the next line of code.) These five samples are the input to the next line of code because they are a natural group determined by the values of the other two columns - i.e. the other two columns are 'Apples' and 'Red'.

Comment: Here is another example: `vcftools --bcf <all_samples.bcf> --weir-fst-pop [Sample_1 Sample_2 Sample_3 Sample_4 Sample_5] --weir-fst-pop <another_sample_file.txt> --out <output_file.txt>` . The square brackets indicate my list of samples that I want to subset from the data. The code example would be one of three iterations: there are three groups of samples: 'Apples Red', 'Apples Green' and 'Apples Yellow'. How do I pull the samples based on these groups?

Comment: This code works to pull the first group of samples, for example: `awk '{ if(($2 == "Apples") && ($3 == "Red")) { print $1 }}'`. But I cannot iterate through this code (I can't seem to be able to replace "Apples" or "Red" with any variables, e.g.  ${variable_1}. I want to be able to take the unique values of the second and third column and iterate through them in order to pull the matching first column (i.e. groups of samples).

Comment: Here is the loop I currently have, which does not work: `for fruit in \`awk '{print $2}' <data_file.txt> | uniq\`
do
for colour in \`awk '{print $3}' <data_file.txt> | uniq\`
do

awk '{ if(($2 == ${fruit}) && ($3 == "${colour}")) { print $1 }}' <data_file.txt>

done
done`

Comment: Please put whatever information we need to understand your question in your question, not in comments under your question or elsewhere. Very few people who are willing to try to help you are going to have the patience to piece together your requirements by reading your question AND comments. Just make it a concise, stand-alone question. As of right now your question sounds simple but your comments look complicated and idk what it is you actually want output given your posted sample input.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
$ awk '{vals[$2 FS $3] = vals[$2 FS $3] OFS $1} END{for (key in vals) print key vals[key]}' file
Apples Red Sample_1 Sample_2 Sample_3 Sample_4 Sample_5
Apples Green Sample_6 Sample_7 Sample_8 Sample_9 Sample_10
Apples Yellow Sample_11 Sample_12 Sample_13 Sample_14 Sample_15
```

or maybe this?

```
$ awk -v fruit='Apples' -v color='Green' '($2==fruit) && ($3==color)' file
Sample_6    Apples  Green
Sample_7    Apples  Green
Sample_8    Apples  Green
Sample_9    Apples  Green
Sample_10   Apples  Green
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple example of a gawk script that parses your input and outputs a transposition of the data that seems suitable to your needs.

```c
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f

# Checks if type (column 2) or subtype (column 3) are 
# different from previous line.
(type != $2) || (subtype != $3) {
    # Prints the start of a new output line.
    # The NR!=1 check avoids that a new line is 
    # printed on the first line.
    printf("%s%s\t%s\t", (NR!=1)?"\n":"", $2, $3);
    type=$2;
    subtype=$3
}
{
    # Prints all sample (column 1) values on the 
    # current output line.
    printf("\"%s\" ", $1);
}
# prints a new line at the end of file.
END{
    print "";
}
```

The output of `script.awk < input.lst` follows. Where `script.awk` is the previous script and `input.lst` is your input example.

```
Apples  Red     "Sample_1" "Sample_2" "Sample_3" "Sample_4" "Sample_5" 
Apples  Green   "Sample_6" "Sample_7" "Sample_8" "Sample_9" "Sample_10" 
Apples  Yellow  "Sample_11" "Sample_12" "Sample_13" "Sample_14" "Sample_15"
```

The script output can be easily manipulated as follows.

```bsh
script.awk < input.lst | while read TYPE SUBTYPE LIST
do 
    echo $TYPE
    echo $SUBTYPE
    for ITEM in $LIST
    do  
        echo execute some command on $ITEM where type is $TYPE and subtype is $SUBTYPE
    done 
done
```

Note that this script is very rough. E.g. there is no error handling and no check for white space or special characters in the input.

Answer (score 0):

Tried with Below script and worked fine

```
for i in "Apples"; do for j in "Red" "Green" "Yellow"; do awk -v i="$i" -v j="$j" 'BEGIN{print "Below are table contains" " " i " and " " " j}$2==i && $NF==j{print $0}' filename; done; done
```

output

```
Below are table contains Apples and  Red
Sample_1    Apples  Red
Sample_2    Apples  Red
Sample_3    Apples  Red
Sample_4    Apples  Red
Sample_5    Apples  Red
Below are table contains Apples and  Green
Sample_6    Apples  Green
Sample_7    Apples  Green
Sample_8    Apples  Green
Sample_9    Apples  Green
Sample_10   Apples  Green
Below are table contains Apples and  Yellow
Sample_11   Apples  Yellow
Sample_12   Apples  Yellow
Sample_13   Apples  Yellow
Sample_14   Apples  Yellow
Sample_15   Apples  Yellow
```